# efficient matrix inversion problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, computational-mathematics

So I'm trying to invert a matrix of the $\begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\
C & D
\end{pmatrix}$ where $A$ and $D$ are square, $D$ is much larger than $A$, and $D$ is diagonal. $A$ $B$ and $C$ have no particular structure. Is there a fast way to do this that takes advantage of D's being diagonal?

Comment: With diagonal matrices being [very easy to invert](http://www.ee.oulu.fi/~mpa/matreng/eem1_5-3.htm), the second version of the formula at [Wikipedia Blockwise Inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Blockwise_inversion) should help

Comment: Also, you can write your matrix as $D'+A'$, where $D'$ is diagonal and $A'$ is sparse. You may then use the [matrix inversion lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) combined with blockwise inversion for potential speedups. You may also want to look into schemes for inverting sparse matrices.

Answer (score 2):

Copied from Wikipedia (for archive purposes):

$\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{A} & \mathbf{B} \\ \mathbf{C} & \mathbf{D} \end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} (\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{BD}^{-1}\mathbf{C})^{-1} & -(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{BD}^{-1}\mathbf{C})^{-1}\mathbf{BD}^{-1} \\ -\mathbf{D}^{-1}\mathbf{C}(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{BD}^{-1}\mathbf{C})^{-1} & \mathbf{D}^{-1}+\mathbf{D}^{-1}\mathbf{C}(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{BD}^{-1}\mathbf{C})^{-1}\mathbf{BD}^{-1}\end{bmatrix}$

In this case we only need to invert D (easy) and $\mathbf{A-BD^{-1}C}$ (hopefully small).

Answer (score 0):

If all the diagonal elements of $D$ were all nonzero, then you could use row and column operations to change the matrix to
$X\begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\
C & D
\end{pmatrix}Y =\begin{pmatrix}
\overline{A} & 0 \\
0 & D
\end{pmatrix}$
and being nonsingular this has an inverse $Z$:

$\begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\
C & D
\end{pmatrix}YZX =I$

If $\overline{A}$ is small, its inverse would not be computationally complex, and likewise D is easy to invert, and the rest is row/column operations.